# Is there a way to simultaneously check if a field is equal to 600+ different values in bash?

Tags: bash, awk

I have gz logs that I need to check that go back the past 12 months to see if one field is equal to 600+ different values. Normally when I do this search I'll do something like this:

```
zcat /logs/logs/log_20210208* | awk -F';' '{OFS=","}{if (($5 = "M") && (($8 ~ /value1/) || ($8 ~ /value2/) || ($8 ~ /value3/) || ($8 ~ /value4/))){print}}'
```

However, this seems tedious to do for 600 different values. Is this achievable using awk?

Comment: If the values live in a file, you can use `grep -f`, but I can't speak to your specific case as I don't know what any of the files look like.

Comment: This probably has little to do with Bash. What tools can you use? Awk, obviously, all standard tools, probably? What about stuff like Perl? Where are those 600 different values stored?

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we ca nhelp you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: I guess you wanted to write *`check if a field matches one of 600+ values`*. For the current formulation there is a very fast answer, that is `# do nothing`. Of course any value cannot be equal to *2* different values at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a file named `values` with your 600 different values in it one per line, this is what you'd do:

```
zcat /logs/logs/log_20210208* |
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{v[$0]; next} ($5 == "M") && ($8 in v)' values -
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much. NR==FNR does that mean it starts over checking the first line of file `values` on each entry it is checking? And I'm assuming $0 is asking to use `values` and setting that to variable `v`. What is next doing?